# Host CrystalReports on a Shared server

Tags: visual-studio, iis, crystal-reports, webserver, shared-hosting

I have installed CrystalReports in a project using VS2019. I want to host this on a shared webserver. I do not have access to install CrystalReportsRuntime on server. What are my options to achieve the same?

I have tried copying all files from Nuget package references but no luck.

Please advise

Comment: Crystal Reports has its own forum, https://answers.sap.com/tags/01200314690800000341

Comment: I think you need to download and install  CrystalReportsRuntime first. Please get the resource from here. https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html

Comment: @BruceZhang I do not have access to shared hosting where I can install runtime.

Comment: CrystalReport application cannot run without runtime in server environment. Please contact the administrator to install runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments mentioned above, I thought of writing it as answer. One cannot run CrystalReports without the runtime being installed on server. So, unless the hosting company installs the runtime, CR wont run on shared hosting. You can chekck this on [Authorized SAP Community Link](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13587777/hosting-crystal-reports-on-shared-hosting-server.html) here.